# stacked and clustered column chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

My problem is regarding stacked and clustered column chart.I'm providing a link below of amcharts

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-clustered-column-chart/#theme-light

what I need to achieve is :

In the above Example you can observe that in javascript code in graphs section particulary in asia-pacific title there was a code like
 "newStack" :true which is dividing the total into two halves i.e europe and northamerica in one bar and rest of the four in another. But what i need is take 2003 i need to have three bars in 2003 and each bar should have all the six(europe----africa) in it.So in total for each year i must have 3 bars like (0-3months)(3-6 months)(6-9months) with all the six visible on each and every bar

Can anyone help me on this code.Thanks in advance.
(please comment if anything is unclear)

Comment: So just remove the `newStack: true` from Europe graph. All segments will then be stacked into a single stack for a category. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you need to work on your question and terms. I'm not sure what you mean by "subgraph", "legend", etc. Maybe create a mockup of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited my question now and i hope it's clear now.

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-easily-create-a-stacked-clustered-column-chart-in-excel/                                                                                what i need would be something like this (first graph in this page)

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/5920bb731a7c062ed3f31ca5086769cb

Comment: I tried this but we have only 6 things right (europe --- africa) and we can't change their names like europe1 and so on. We need to have the same 6 for all the 9 bars. I uploaded a link in which there were excel graphs. I need something like that means only six colours .

Comment: You can change the graph titles the way you want it to. And you can hide graphs from appearing in legend by setting it's property `visibleInLegend: false`

Comment: Every bar would be getting data like take europe and in all the 9 bars europe must be of same colour and in the same ways all the other. So in total i must have only 6 colours for all 9 bars.

Comment: http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-easily-create-a-stacked-clustered-column-chart-in-excel/                                                                        this is the link i would suggest you in which there is a bargraph with product1 and product2 on x axes . If you can provide anything similar to that it would suffice my problem.

Comment: I believe you can take it from there. You can set color for each graph explicitly http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColors

Comment: I tried this but i'm unable to get what i require. Could you provide me a more detailed solution of what i need to do ?                                                                http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-easily-create-a-stacked-clustered-column-chart-in-excel/                                                                              Something like this especially i'm unable to get same colors if you can do for the above mentioned example it would be very helpful .                             Thank you

Comment: Even, i have the same requirement, wasn't able to figure it out yet.